# what is the use of form-group in bootstrap 4?

Tags: forms, bootstrap-4

I am currently working on creating a form and I don't Understand what is the use of form-group?

Below example contains form-group inside div

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <input type="text" placeholder=" Company Name *">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <input type="text" placeholder=" Contact Number *">
                    </div>
                 </div>
```

Below example doesn't contain form-group but still displays the same result then what is the purpose of form-group:

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input type="text" placeholder=" Company Name *">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input type="text"  placeholder=" Contact Number *">
                    </div>
                 </div>
```

Comment: It has margin-bottom set on it so that in case of more than 1 form fields, there is some space between the 2 fields. Qoute : "The .form-group class is the easiest way to add some structure to forms. It provides a flexible class that encourages proper grouping of labels, controls, optional help text, and form validation messaging. By default it only applies margin-bottom, but it picks up additional styles in .form-inline as needed. Use it with <fieldset>s, <div>s, or nearly any other element."

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-groups

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group ">
            <input type="text" placeholder=" Company Name *">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder=" Contact Number *">
          </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please add some comment to your answer. The code on its own explains nothing.